# Add element at the beginning of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, insert

I don't understand why this function doesn't add an element at the beginning of the linked list. Head remain the same.

```
typedef struct node_struct{
    int data;
    struct node_struct *next;
}node;

void beginning(node *head){
     node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
     int value;
     printf("Insert a number to add at the beginning: ");
     scanf("%d",&value);
     new->data = value;
     new->next = head;
}
```

Comment: You never update the list head, so after the call it still points to the old list head.  You need to return the new head to the caller (or add a level of indirection to `head` and change it in through the pointer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change

```
void beginning(node *head){
```

to

```
void beginning(node **head){
```

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct NODE{
    int data;
    struct NODE *next;
}node;

typedef struct NODE *Tode;
void create(Tode *head){

     *head = malloc(sizeof(node));
     (*head)->next = NULL;
}
void beginning(Tode *head, int numSize){
    Tode new;
    int value, i;
    for(i = 0; i < numSize; i++){
        new = malloc(sizeof(node));
        scanf("%d",&value);
        new->data = value;
        new->next = (*head)->next;
        (*head)->next = new;
    }
}
void printList(Tode head){
    Tode ptr;
    ptr = head->next;
    printf("\nprint List's value\n");
    while(ptr){
        printf("%d ",ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main(){
    node *head;
    int numSize;
    create(&head);
    printf("Insert how many  number to add at the beginning: ");
    scanf("%d",&numSize);
    beginning(&head, numSize);
    printList(head);
    // delete(&head);        // youself do
}
```

run result:

```
Insert how many  number to add at the beginning: 5
1 3 6 8 235

print List's value
235 8 6 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointer to pointer to deal with the problem.
Also you can return new begin from beginning().

```
node *new_begin(const node *head) {
    node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    /* add new node information */
    return new;
}
```

Comment: I did it with "return" but I'd like to use pointer to pointer, can you explain better?

Comment: I think use return approach can add const qualifier to head, it may guarantee less side-effect.